# How to create a floating panel that appears in whole screen in MacOS with swift

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

What I need to create is whole screen overlay like in this screenshot:

[image]

I have created a floating panel using this code:

```swift
import SwiftUI


class FloatingPanel<Content: View>: NSPanel {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    init(view: () -> Content,
             contentRect: NSRect,
             backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType = .buffered,
             defer flag: Bool = false,
             isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
        /// Initialize the binding variable by assigning the whole value via an underscore
        self._isPresented = isPresented
     
        /// Init the window as usual
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect,
                    styleMask: [.nonactivatingPanel, .titled, .resizable, .closable, .fullSizeContentView],
                    backing: backing,
                    defer: flag)
     
        /// Allow the panel to be on top of other windows
        isFloatingPanel = true
        level = .popUpMenu
     
        /// Allow the panel to be overlaid in a fullscreen space
        collectionBehavior.insert(.fullScreenPrimary)
     
        /// Don't show a window title, even if it's set
        titleVisibility = .hidden
        titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
     
        /// Since there is no title bar make the window moveable by dragging on the background
        isMovableByWindowBackground = true
     
        /// Hide when unfocused
        hidesOnDeactivate = true
     
        /// Hide all traffic light buttons
        standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
     
        /// Sets animations accordingly
        animationBehavior = .utilityWindow
     
        /// Set the content view.
        /// The safe area is ignored because the title bar still interferes with the geometry
        contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: view()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .environment(\.floatingPanel, self))
    }
    
    /// Close automatically when out of focus, e.g. outside click
    override func resignMain() {
        super.resignMain()
        close()
    }
     
    /// Close and toggle presentation, so that it matches the current state of the panel
    override func close() {
        super.close()
        isPresented = false
    }
     
    /// `canBecomeKey` and `canBecomeMain` are both required so that text inputs inside the panel can receive focus
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
     
    override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
}

private struct FloatingPanelKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: NSPanel? = nil
}
 
extension EnvironmentValues {
  var floatingPanel: NSPanel? {
    get { self[FloatingPanelKey.self] }
    set { self[FloatingPanelKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}
```

and a modifier extension for set it up

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// Add a  ``FloatingPanel`` to a view hierarchy
fileprivate struct FloatingPanelModifier<PanelContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    /// Determines wheter the panel should be presented or not
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
 
    /// Determines the starting size of the panel
    var contentRect: CGRect = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame ?? .zero
 
    /// Holds the panel content's view closure
    @ViewBuilder let view: () -> PanelContent
 
    /// Stores the panel instance with the same generic type as the view closure
    @State var panel: FloatingPanel<PanelContent>?
 
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                /// When the view appears, create, center and present the panel if ordered
                panel = FloatingPanel(view: view, contentRect: contentRect, isPresented: $isPresented)
                panel?.center()
                if isPresented {
                    present()
                }
            }.onDisappear {
                /// When the view disappears, close and kill the panel
                panel?.close()
                panel = nil
            }.onChange(of: isPresented) { value in
                /// On change of the presentation state, make the panel react accordingly
                if value {
                    present()
                } else {
                    panel?.close()
                }
            }
    }
 
    /// Present the panel and make it the key window
    func present() {
        panel?.orderFront(nil)
        panel?.makeKey()
    }
    
    
}


extension View {
    /** Present a ``FloatingPanel`` in SwiftUI fashion
     - Parameter isPresented: A boolean binding that keeps track of the panel's presentation state
     - Parameter contentRect: The initial content frame of the window
     - Parameter content: The displayed content
     **/
    func floatingPanel<Content: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
                                      contentRect: CGRect = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame ?? .zero,
                                      @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        self.modifier(FloatingPanelModifier(isPresented: isPresented, contentRect: contentRect, view: content))
    }
}
```

I have tried to modify this code but still I wasn't able to achieve a whole screen overlay. I even try by setting the `NSwindow.level` to `.popupmenu` but that didn't work.

Is there any way that I can create a whole screen overlay?

Comment: Which part of whole screen window can you not achieve? Full-screen? Highest level?

Comment: i am unable to get it over the dock and menu bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to use `NSWindow` instead of `NSPanel`:
`NSWindow` has a method called [`toggleFullscreen(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419527-togglefullscreen) that does what you need.